# Does one have to mention every single publication they have worked on, in their SOP? (PhD CS USA)

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, cv, statement-of-purpose

**Background:** Undergraduate applying to PhD CS programs in the US.

I currently have quite a few posters/publications and manuscripts under review for a domain X.

I have structured my SOP around the fact that I want to do research in this domain X and want to work with professors who are in the domain X at the university I will be applying too.

***The issue is,*** SOPs have a strict word limit and I am not able to mention 1 review paper (under review, second author) of mine because the word limit is exceeding (hard limit).

**Question:**

- Is this taken negatively in any sense by a PhD Panel?
- Should I remove that paper from my CV? (It is under the "in-review" section).

Comment: I am not in CS, but I would guess: Yes, put them in the CV; but you need not mention them in the SOP.

Comment: Does the 'yes' mean the panel will not take in a positive manner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already mention most of your papers in your SOP. I assume this one is the least important, otherwise you would have left out another article. This should be fine, it is mentioned in your CV so if they want they can be aware of the paper. They will probably not notice, or when they notice not deem the paper relevant enough to be included in your SOP.  Nobody will take this negatively.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. This was exactly what I was looking for.